# Get outlook retention policy for all folders

Tags: powershell, outlook, windows-10, policy, retention

My organization implemented a centralized retention policies. They said that we have to apply required policy for each folder we want the policy to differ from the default one.
How I can get a recursive list of all my outlook folders with information like name, size and retention policy? It would probably be a Powershell script.

Additional requirement: the script must run on user's machine.

```
Folder name | Size | Retention policy
-------------------------------------
folder 1    | 1GB  | policy 1
folder 2    | 2GB  | policy 2
```

With following script I can get all folders (but not subfolders):

```bsh
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Account = $n.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'User.Name@domain.com' }
$Account.Folders | Format-Table Name -AutoSize
```

Comment: Kindly share your piece of effort that you have tried. You can get it `Get-MailboxFolder -Identity Username:\Inbox` or you can play with `Get-MailboxFolder`. But thats not the case. You need to explore and let us know where you are stuck currently.

Comment: I don't have these commands on user's machine.

Comment: This cmdlet is available in on-premises Exchange and in the cloud-based service. Some parameters and settings may be exclusive to one environment or the other.
Use the Get-MailboxFolder cmdlet to view folders in your own mailbox. Administrators can't use this cmdlet to view folders in other mailboxes (the cmdlet is available only from the MyBaseOptions user role).

Comment: I'm looking for a way for users to check how retention policy affects their folders. Users will run this script by themselves.

Comment: If a "comobject outlook.application" can help, you may take a look at my (long time ago made) PowerShell module OutlookConnector. It is available on PS Gallery (`Install-Module -Name OutlookConnector -Scope CurrentUser`) and you can find the link there to GitHub. Though, I was not able to find this information inside of that object. The closest I got was RetentionExpirationDate for each message. You can get it with something like `(Get-OutlookFolder -Recurse | ? Name -eq MyFolder).Items | Select -Expand RetentionExpirationDate -ea 0 | Select -Unique`

Comment: Thank you Igor. After running command I got a result "Saturday, 1 January 4501 12:00:00 AM" :)